# Why program crashes when using integer value in setText?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set text in my button .

> answers is an `ArrayList` of Integers

On converting it to `string` it works perfectly

```
button0.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
```

But on using integer value my app crashes.

```
button0.setText(answers.get(0));
```

Any suggestions why this happening ?

As `TextView.seText()` easily set the integer text to it but why button is unable to do it ?

Comment: Crashes? Are you sure you are not talking about a compiler error? Hint : read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Because there's a difference between *integer text* (the ASCII representation of the digit `0`) and the *integer* zero. Numbers are not characters. They're numbers, which is why they're called integers and not characters or strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because setText() only expects string or char[].

So either you can perform type casting or you can add quotes with the number

- By type casting String.valueOf(number)
- By adding "" with the number quantityTextView.setText(""+number); or
  quantityTextView.setText(number+"");
- textView.setText(Integer.toString(number));

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because setText() expects a String as argument. Just do like this

```
String.valueOf(integer)
```

And thus will work.